# What should I do when my flag for a clearly bad question gets disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, triage, disputed-flags

I know that I'm a little aggressive in flagging things as unsalvageable in Triage, so I understand that some of those flags will end up getting disputed. But today there are two questions that I've flagged that *clearly* needed to be closed where my flag was disputed within 5 minutes.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748520/multiple-user-registration-forms-for-different-types-of-users-in-wordpress) the asker is explicitly asking us to suggest a Wordpress plugin. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756224/tips-sql-server-data-debuging) (closed while I was typing up the post you're reading now) the asker just wants general tips for "debugging data" in SQL Server. I know that a lot of questions are borderline, but I'm having trouble thinking of an argument for why these questions could possibly be acceptable.

When my flag gets disputed like this but I'm **sure** the question should be closed, what's the appropriate response? I can't re-flag with the same flag. Should I use a custom flag to ask a moderator to look at it? Should I come whine here on meta and get them closed by the meta bandwagon? Downvote them and move on, letting the site slowly fill with questions that should have been closed & deleted?

Comment: _Should I use a custom flag to ask a moderator to look at it?_ Nope, don't do that. This is not something that warrants a moderator.

Comment: I agree with bluefeet: reflagging is not a good idea.  However I believe that SO should automatically "undispute" and mark your flag as helpful if the question is closed or put on hold, especially for the very reason you flagged it.  I just had the same thing happen to me.

Comment: That Wordpress question sounds familiar to me... oh wait, I flagged it too. Disputed, of course. It's really frustrating. I know that disputed flags "don't count against me" or anything, but still... what's the point of flagging if the triage queue dismisses them so easily? It would be OK to dispute or even decline them, if the consensus is "looks OK", but "should be improved" is kind of a grey area, I feel like there is *a lot* of people using it instead of skipping when they are unsure if a question is unsalvageable or not...

Comment: Just ran into this very issue. It's annoying that the only way to have it solved is to post on Meta... It's weird too. Since the flag was disputed, it never made it into the Close Vote queue, right? So why can't we flag again?

Answer (score 4):

> Should I come whine here on meta and get them closed by the meta bandwagon?

Well, it worked in this case.  Both questions are now deleted.  So far as I can tell, this is basically what the [disputed-flags](/questions/tagged/disputed-flags) tag is for.

As someone with access to the close queue, let me show you something:

[image: Screenshot of the close queue, with 6.7 thousand questions in it.]

There are a *lot* of questions flagged for closure at any given time.  The system is very high volume and flags do tend to get misprocessed or even aged away as a result.  Downvotes can act as a substitute for close votes, [in some cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).  If that's not good enough (e.g. the question has an answer), sure, bring it to Meta and we'll pile-on close vote it for you.  Assuming, of course, it really should be closed.

Side note: anyone want to merge [disputed-flags](/questions/tagged/disputed-flags) with [declined-flags](/questions/tagged/declined-flags)?  They technically mean slightly different things, but I see no good reason to draw that rather pedantic distinction in the tagging system, especially when half the questions are in the wrong tag and neither wiki explains the difference.