# Disputed flags & questions closed for the same reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, disputed-flags

This is to address cases of raised flags in triage that get disputed automatically and the question end up being closed or placed on hold for the same reason (or similar).

One of my own examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8655245

Where the flag was disputed:
[image: flag queue log - disputed flag]

And the [question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182412/cakephp-array-into-tablesql-single-column) was later re-flagged for the same reason:
[image: Triage decision and final question state]

It seems this is a recurring problem:

- [Re-flag aged away flags with the same flag reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287317/re-flag-aged-away-flags-with-the-same-flag-reason)
- [Disputed flag on closed question for same reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297260/disputed-flag-on-closed-question-for-same-reason)
- [Please rename the "Should be improved" button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button)
- [Auto-convert disputed flags when they prove to be correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293611/auto-convert-disputed-flags-when-they-prove-to-be-correct)
- [What should I do when my flag for a clearly bad question gets disputed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290896/what-should-i-do-when-my-flag-for-a-clearly-bad-question-gets-disputed)
- [Are raised flags during triage disputed if others disagree?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289386/are-raised-flags-during-triage-disputed-if-others-disagree)

### Possible solutions

If the dispute is done automatically through triage, wouldn't it be more viable to show the raised flags before a person chooses an option in triage? Or perhaps just a simple count with the raised flags?

If this may influence the person to raise flags in triage, it may actually be the best option in the end:

- it would avoid the question to be re-addressed and re-flagged;
- it would also encourage people to use flags appropriately, instead of choosing the popular "should be improved" option (SBI);
- currently many users may choose SBI for not accumulating disputed flags;
- triage would become truly efficient in flagging and closing poor questions.

Another way to encourage people to use flags in triage (without a flags preview in it), would be to update a disputed flag to *helpful* (even if the reason does not match exactly).

If this is not feasible, when the question is closed, a recheck of previous flags in triage could be made automatically in order to include the username in the list.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, added to the question.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293611/auto-convert-disputed-flags-when-they-prove-to-be-correct

Comment: @NathanOliver Exactly! Appreciated.

Comment: I don't think people should be told their flags were helpful if the reasons don't match, it may encourage inaccurate use of flags. The goal should be to get people flagging accurately, not *just* flagging more.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I get that, but you also know that "too-broad" and "unclear" flags are sometimes both appropriate for particular questions and the "off-topic" reason may also overlap them (e.g. a question without code or a proper description of the error).

Comment: @Armfoot I agree that they may overlap, but the system should treat them as separate cases, otherwise there's no point in having both.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan exactly! The system would identify them as different flags, but in the end, you know that both kinds were helpful in those cases...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's a good idea to show the flags which have already been raised. This will bias the reviewers towards raising the same flag without much consideration. You basically give people the choice of:

1. spending zero effort on thinking and raise the same flag, which will likely be deemed helpful, or
2. spending some effort to actually read the question and decide which issues make it bad, but your flag will have less chances to be considered helpful.

I believe the way to go is: [Auto-convert disputed flags when they prove to be correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293611/auto-convert-disputed-flags-when-they-prove-to-be-correct)

Comment: Biasing may only be a problem if the question does not have serious issues in it. And before you choose an option in triage, you can get a lot more biased by the feedback given through up/down votes and comments...

Comment: Well, that's one more source of such bias. It's even worse actually: not only are you biased, but you're also **motivated** to raise the same flag and increase your helpful flags total.

Comment: Ok, take a _spam_ example. There's no doubt that triage should close it. But sometimes, it's written in a way where only following the link you can understand its spam. Some people don't even bother to follow the link, and may vote SBI or OK. Take [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206000/how-to-customize-jquery-plugin) where you can see that there will be no answer because of its incompleteness, but you can clearly see that will end (or already has ended) up in the SBI category. Again, biasing is only a problem when there are no serious issues in it...

Comment: @Armfoot I have never seen spam questions survive long enough to become a problem. Usually the first user to discover the link is spam/malicious writes a comment about it.

Comment: Since we're talking hypothetically: in that apparently OK question, the first user followed the link and got some _free malaware_, he flagged the question as _spam_, but it got auto-rejected by triage due to SBI. Since the question remained active, 10 more viewers got that _free malaware_ until the spam flag was raised once again, which means that little flag biasing would have been useful for everyone after all...